# When I push values to array asyncronously, the array size increases but the values are blank

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code. The code is erroring because the array Emails is full of null values.
However, when I debug, the 'row' event is firing and the data object does indeed have the property `.Email`. For example, data object is correctly `{Email:'jon.doe@example.com'}` however the line `emails.push(data.Email);` results in the emails array being the correct length but full of null values. `[null,null,null...]` How is this even possible? I'm using Node.js 14.15

```
    const emails = [];
    await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        parser.on('row',(data)=>{
            emails.push(data.Email);
        });
        parser.on('done',()=>{
            return resolve();
        });
        parser.on('error',(error)=>{
            console.error(error);
            return reject(error);
        });
        parser.getEmails(path.join(folder,file));
    });
    console.log(emails.length + ' emails loaded');
```

Comment: What do you see if you use `console.log(data.Email)`?

Comment: How are you viewing the `data` object? I suspect something is modifying it asynchronously, and the console is showing you the updated contents, which weren't there when you did `emails.push()`

Comment: @Barmar console.log(data.Email) is the email, console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) shows object with property email, you may be right about the async modification though

Comment: the script isn't doing anything else at the same time, do you think the strings could get garbage collected with the object?

Comment: No. Garbage collection doesn't do that.

Comment: I didn't mean that something else is adding it, but that it's part of the way this asychronous parser works.

Comment: If you put `console.log(emails)` right after `emails.push(data.Email)` do you see the correct emails?

Comment: @Barmar console.log(emails) is array of undefined. Running console.log(Object.keys(data)) returns ["Email"]

Comment: Then I don't see how `console.log(data.Email)` can be non-null at the same time.

Comment: Try `console.log(data.Email, JSON.stringify(emails));`

Comment: @Barmar thanks for helping me with this. It turned out that someone accidentally added an ascii control character into the title of the CSV. So the key is not `Email` but invisible character + Email, now it all makes sense

Answer (score 0):

So basically, in short, I was assuming that the property was correctly labeled `Email`. However it turned out that the field was actually `[random invisible ascii control character]Email`. So of course logging out the strings to console would not flag the issue for visual inspection.  After much hair pulling, and pulling the production file to development side and examining the code in a debugger I was able to determine that the key name was different than expected. So a more robust code turns out to be something like:

```
    let emails = [];
    await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        parser.on('row',(data)=>{
            emails.push(data);
        });
        parser.on('done',()=>{
            return resolve();
        });
        parser.on('error',(error)=>{
            console.error(error);
            return reject(error);
        });
        parser.getEmails(path.join(folder,file));
    });
    if(emails.length === 0) {
        return; //handle no emails here
    }
    const key = Object.keys(emails[0]).filter(i=>i.includes('Email'));
    if(key.length === 0) {
        return; //handle improper field title here
    }
    emails = emails.map(i=>i[key[0]]);
    console.log(emails.length + ' emails loaded');
```